# OpenCV grayscale ignore red color

Tags: c#, android, opencv, image-processing, xamarin.android

I am making app for recognize digits (OCR) so I need to prepare imamge for it. There is no problem when i take photo to blue, green, yellow or other color but red digits become so gray after grayscale in OpenCV and these digits became unable to recognize.

Original image:
[image]

Image after grayscale (yellow and red digits):
[image]

Image after threshold:

[image]

As you can see, after it red digits are gone.

Here is fragment of code, that I use:

```
mat.ConvertTo(mat, CvType.Cv8uc1);
Imgproc.CvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.ColorBgr2gray);
Imgproc.Threshold(mat, mat, 127, 255, Imgproc.ThreshBinary);
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Try a different threshold or try using each of the RGB channels separately. It looks promising.

Comment: Your problem is, that pure red has a very low luminosity (~76) and that the surrounding grey is at ~50, so there's not that much difference between the values, especially for thresholding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeru Luke's solution should be fairly robust for a wide range of input images. But if you need raw speed, you might think about a simple brightness/contrast operation followed by global thresholding.

If you use brightness and contrast, which is computationally cheap, you can make the background become all black and then use global thresholding to get a nice binarized image.

Photo editors (Photoshop, Gimp, etc.) often use brightness/contrast scale of ±127. The mathematical formala for simultaneously adding brightness (b) and contrast (c) is

> img = (1 + c/127)*img + (b-c)

If you have access to `mat` from C#, then you can use the [cv.mat.convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#) function:

```
cv.Mat.convertTo( OutputArray, cv.CV_8U, 1+c/127, b-c)
```

For your image I used b = -45 and c = +45

Then convert to grayscale and binarize (I used threshold of 50 on your image)

**Update**

The OP was tagged for C#. But many of us use Python. In Python, we have no access to Mat. However, we can use the `cv2.addWeighted` function which does:

> dst = src1*alpha + src2*beta + gamma

If we set beta = 0, then this becomes equivalent to `cv.Mat.convertTo` scaling. This seems to be faster than doing matrix operations in Numpy. Numpy is a little slower because we have to do some extra stuff to handle overflow.

Comment: Wonderful insight +1

Comment: Can you provide me this formula working for dark blue digits on light blue background?

Comment: For dark digits on light background, you'll have to play with brightness and contrast until the background goes away. Then you'll want to convert to grayscale and binarize. When you binarize, you'll want to invert the colors so that your now black digits become white and the white background becomes black.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comments you can perform Otsu threshold to each of the color channels R, G, B.

Otsu threshold of Blue channel:

[image]

Otsu threshold of Green channel:

[image]

Otsu threshold of Red channel:

[image]

Finally I added all the above to get the following result:

[image]

I only used the following functions:

1. `cv2.threshold()`
2. `cv2.add()`

### UPDATE

**Code**

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

#--- performs Otsu threshold ---
def threshold(img, st):
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'res_' + str(st) + '.jpg'), thresh) 
    return  thresh

path = r'C:\Users\Desktop'
filename = 'digits.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, filename))
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)   #--- resized the image because it was to big 
cv2.imshow('Original', img)

#--- see each of the channels individually ---
cv2.imshow('b', img[:,:,0])
cv2.imshow('g', img[:,:,1])
cv2.imshow('r', img[:,:,2])

m1 = threshold(img[:,:,0], 1)   #--- threshold on blue channel
m2 = threshold(img[:,:,1], 2)   #--- threshold on green channel
m3 = threshold(img[:,:,2], 3)   #--- threshold on red channel

#--- adding up all the results above ---
res = cv2.add(m1, cv2.add(m2, m3))

cv2.imshow('res', res)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'res.jpg'), res)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you provide me Python code for threshold all channels separately?